# Problem: DRC Tutorial: Sending Joint Position Commands to Atlas Joint Controller over ROS Topic

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working in this tutorial:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.7/sending_joint_controller_commands_over_ros

And when try to:

```
roscreate-pkg drcsim_joint_commands_tutorial roscpp trajectory_msgs osrf_msgs
```

Get this error:

```
ERROR: dependency [osrf_msgs] cannot be found
```

A lot of thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5449/problem:-drc-tutorial:-sending-joint-position-commands-to-atlas-joint-controller-over-ros-topic/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-02-09**:
@scpeters,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`osrf_msgs` is a ros package distributed in the osrf-common debian on packages.osrfoundation.org. If you installed drcsim using apt-get (according to the [installation instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/InstallDRC)), then the package should be on your system. Use the following command to search for it:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep osrf
```

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-02-10**:
as a matter of fact I have this package

```
ii  osrf-common                                  1.1.0-2~precise                                     Software and messages used in multiple OSRF projects
```

However when try to upgrading to DRCsim have a problem with this package

```
 drcsim-groovy : Depende: osrf-common-groovy pero no va a instalarse
                         Depende: sandia-hand-groovy pero no va a instalarse
```

I used:

```
  $ sudo apt-get -f install drcsim-groovy
```

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-02-10**:
@jose-luis-rivero Any ideas?